# Backup Ubuntu using Acronis

Tags: ubuntu, backup, acronis-trueimage

Wondering if it's possible to backup Ubuntu using Acronis Home edition the way so I can have all MBR and mouting points essensial for Ubuntu backed up. Prefer to boot from CD/USB and backup into network. Anyone have done this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use any backup software to do a complete copy of your hard drive, try using any of the applications included with the [hirens boot cd](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/), inside the Backup Tools of the DOS programs or the Ghost (optional) from the live Windows that HBC includes.

good luck!

Comment: I don't need a complete hard drive backup, rather I have one windows and one ubuntu partitions which I need to backup.

Comment: you could backup the complete disk or only a partition, but I think you can't backup your mbr, but with ubuntu you can reinstall the mbr (grub in this case) with grub-install [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows)